# Perforce -- unlink permission denied on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, perforce

I'm trying to `p4 sync`, but I got a "Can't clobber writable file" error. So, I removed the writable permission, but now I get this error:

```
$ ls -l file.txt
-r--r--r--  1 myusername  admin   1.0K Jan 1 00:00 file.txt

$ p4 sync file.txt
//the/depot/directory/file.txt#5 - deleted as /my/local/workspace/directory/file.txt
unlink: /my/local/workspace/directory/file.txt: Permission denied
```

I am logged in as `myusername`. Why am I getting permission denied?

Comment: I've had the same problem in Windows, and making the file read-only solved it.

Comment: In order to unlink a file, the permissions on the parent **directory** are relevant. So knowing the permissions on /my/local/workspace/directory would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I getting permission denied?

Because you just took away your own write permission. That means you no longer have permission to write to the file. Which means p4, acting on your behalf, no longer has permission to write to the file. Which means that when p4, acting on your behalf, asks for permission to write to the file, it's denied. Which means p4 says "Permission denied".

What else did you expect to happen?

The reason `p4 sync` is complaining is that you appear to have a file that you've checked out (and therefore possibly made changes to) and it doesn't know about it, so it refuses to just overwrite your hard work. You should manually revert the file, if that's what you want to do.

Perforce keeps track of what state it expects your files to be in. If it left a file with non-writable access, and expects it to still be in that state, it will attempt to chmod it before overwriting it. But if it thinks the file should be writable, it will just open it and try to write it. The fact that a chmod would succeed is irrelevant if p4 never calls it.

At any rate, the solution is to explicitly revert the file, delete it and re-pull it, etc.

Comment: But the file wasn't checked out and is identical to the one on the depot.

Comment: Something you did made the file writable, so p4 assumed that you must have checked it out. It may have assumed wrong. But it doesn't really matter; you still have to revert the file, or just delete the local copy and re-sync it. If you know for sure the file is identical, there's no risk in doing so.

Comment: Could it be that the file is opened in an editor or other app? Perforce normally has no trouble updating unchecked-out, read-only files in your workspace.

Comment: @user1054341: I'm not sure whether you're suggesting that as an explanation for the initial "Can't clobber writable file", or for the later "permission denied". But it doesn't explain either. The first error means that p4 expected the file to be read-only, but it wasn't (because the user did something to change it). The second error means that it got an EACCES error. On Windows, most apps open files exclusively, which means someone else trying to access the same file fails, but on POSIX (including OS X), things don't work that way.

Comment: @abarnert: I was addressing the later "permission denied". You're right, having the file open an editor shouldn't affect that on POSIX. But something is preventing Perforce from modifying the file, and it's not that the file is read-only, because 'p4 sync' ONLY operates on read-only files. (Unless the client's 'allwrite' option is set.)

Comment: @DarrenGreen: Does your client view have Altroots set? And/or the 'rmdir' option? I vaguely recall some combination of those could end up with Perforce trying to access a file in a directory that doesn't exist. Sorry I can't remember the details.

Comment: @user1054341 No, I don't have Altroots set or the rmdir option, but I will look into something like this! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing file permissions, you can do a `p4 sync -f`. But take care, it can be dangerous:

> Force the sync. Perforce performs the sync even if the client workspace already has the file at the specified revision. If the file is writable, it is overwritten.
>   This option does not affect open files, but it does override the noclobber client option.

So make sure to commit your work before doing it.